# I can't figure out why my page is rendering differently in different browsers

Tags: css, cross-browser

I'm using the Yahoo CSS reset, and all of my CSS uses pixel values rather than relative measures like ems. **You'll notice that the bottom right corner of the div containing the form is shifted in Chrome from where it is in FireFox.**

Check it out:
http://jsfiddle.net/rhewitt/anMmX/

**Chrome:**
[image: Chrome]

**FireFox**
[image: FireFox]

```
/*header style*/
html{
background:url(../Images/textureslice.png) repeat;
}

body {
font-family:Georgia;
color:#93b9bb;
}

/* Links */
li a{
color:#93b9bb;
text-decoration:none;
}

li a:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
color:#6b8f91;
}

/* Navigation Structure */
#nav {
width:920px;
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
padding-top:120px;
list-style-type:none;
}

#outterBox li{
display:inline-block;
padding:0 50px;
position:relative;  
}
#linksLeft{
float:left;
border-top:3px solid #93b9bb;
border-bottom:3px solid #93b9bb;
margin:60px 0 0 25px;
padding:5px 0;
}   

#linksLeft li ul {
background-color:#93b9bb;
margin-top:10px;
border-radius:6px;
}

#amy {
clear:both;
font-weight:bold;
letter-spacing:6px;
font-size:120%;
}
#talent{
font-size:70%;
}
#logo {
    float:left;
background:url(../Images/logocropped.png) no-repeat;
height:134px;
width:160px;
}

#linksRight{
float:left;
border-top:3px solid #93b9bb;
border-bottom:3px solid #93b9bb;
margin-top:60px;
padding:5px 0;
}

/* Subnavigation menu */
#linksLeft li ul li {
display:block;
padding:10px 15px;
text-align:left;
}

#subNav a{ 
color:#FFF;
}

#subNav {
position:absolute;
left:10px;
top:15px;
z-index:999;
}

#subnavborder {
margin:10px 10px;
border: 6px solid white;
border-radius:6px;
}
#nav ul ul {
display:none;
}

#nav ul li:hover > ul {
display:block;
}
```

Comment: Bottom left corner or bottom right corner?

Comment: I can't replicate this error, even with your code untouched - do you have this a a live web page, some of the resources are missing and might help to see what's happening?

Comment: Bottom right, sorry!  I'm running this on LAMP -> localhost; not in production yet.  All the resources are included in the jsfiddle, I couldn't get the html formatted here -- no jscript yet.

Comment: So I see a few things going on here. For me, I'm seeing the same behavior in Firefox and Chrome shown by your Chrome screenshot. If you were to add `right: 22px;` to your `#form` selector, it would band-aid your form element's right alignment, BUT you may still have problems with other parts of your layout due to other weirdness :)

Comment: I'm going to fiddle with your fiddle and see if I can rein in some of the styles. Hope you don't mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text size for the browser was set > 100% (not page zoom).  This caused the rendering to be wonky on my machine and also explains why it couldn't be replicated by others.

Answer (score -1):

I cant replicate the difference either.

Did you clear cache in chrome? Try reloading by shift+f5.

I assume it should look like the second screenshot.

http://jsfiddle.net/xLTE4/

Adjust the buttons css right propperty and it should be fine in both browsers, at least it works on my end.

Also consider maybe doing this layout without everything being positioned absolutely.

```
#submitBtn{
    position:absolute;
    right:45px;
    top:430px;
    width:80px;
}
```

Comment: Cleared the cache -- same result.  What do you suggest for positioning? floats?  This is my first project so I'm more than open to suggestions.

Comment: This just sounds like an attempt to start a discussion with the OP.   What exactly is this answer?

Comment: @sparky i have included code which will fix the problem. read maybe?

Comment: yes, i would do this with floats not absolute position. you could make most of the graphics into a single background image and then position the form fields, floating labels to inputs, then position the form element using margins.

Comment: Yeah, I read it, but you obviously didn't understand my comment, so here it goes again:  Your answer is a series of questions and suggestions, rather than a _concise solution_ to the problem.  This is not a discussion forum.

Comment: no its not. there is code when employed which solves the problem.